# Getting values of nested objects and arrays - with plunker

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have two arrays, with nested objects, downloaded as part of calls to API endpoints, one (preview) has just numbers.

Example:

```
[{
  obj1:[1, 2],
  obj2:[3, 4]
}]
```

I had to make a second call to another endpoint, to get a list of IDs with strings

Example:

```
[{
  obj1:[{
    id:1,
    name:'string_name1'
  }, {
    id:2, 
    name:'string_name2'
  }]
}, {
  obj2:[{
    id:3, 
    name:'string_name3'
  }, {
    id:4, 
    name:'string_name4'
  }]
}];
```

I need to match the IDs to the first array of objects numbers, so I have strings/text values to display on my web page

I have 2 functions

The first one, pulls the numbers from the preview array and pushes them to my own editable array that I will use to display on the page

This is the array before function runs

```
 objName = [['obj1'], ['obj2']];
```

This is the first function, matches the names in preview to the names in my array and pushes values

```
    setNumbers(){
     for(let i = 0; i < this.objName.length; i++){
           for(var name in this.preview[0]) {
             if (name == this.objName[i][0]){
                  for(var val in  this.preview[0][name]) {
                       this.objName[i].push(this.preview[0][name][val])
                  }
             }

          }
     }
  this.setStrings()
}
```

The second matches the IDs in fields to the numbers in objName and replaces with the string value

```
public setStrings(){
  let feildId, feildName;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++){
      var obj = this.fields[i]
        for(var name in obj) {
          if(this.objName[i][0] == name){
              for(let j = 0; j < obj[name].length; j++){
                feildId = obj[name][j].id
                feildName = obj[name][j].name;
                  for(let x = 0; x < this.objName[i].length; x++){
                    if (this.objName[i][x] == feildId){
                       var index = this.objName[i].indexOf(feildId)
                         if (index !== -1) {
                              this.objName[i][index] = feildName;
                          }

                    }
                  }
              }
          }
        }
    }

console.log(this.objName)
  }
```

The objName array, for output, ends up looking like:

```
[['obj1', 'string_name1', 'string_name2'], ['obj2', 'string_name3', 'string_name4']]
```

It works, but makes my eyes hurt, there must be an easier cleaner way of doing this?

Plunker link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/KBDu3ZehHl04er6eut6r?p=preview

Comment: It might be best if you show what you'd like the result to look like

Comment: Thanks for your reply Phil, I've updated my question, let me know if I can make things any clearer

Comment: Does the first array in your question actually serve any purpose? It looks like your result could be entirely constructed based on the information in the second array - obj1 goes with the first two strings and obj2 goes with the second two.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I make a http call to an API endpoint, this is only part of what it gives me, I have to then make another call, to download a full list of info, to match the IDs in the first call to the strings in the second call, in reality, the second array is a lot longer than the one you see here and not all of it is used

Comment: @Roy Ok, one more question: the first array is an array containing a single object. Will it always contain just one object, or could it contain several? If the latter, what should happen when it contains several objects?

Comment: @JLRishe That's correct yes, always an array with one object and arrays within that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structures are not ideal for this kind of transformation. For instance, it would have been better if the display strings could be addressed directly given an "obj"-property and array index, without having to iterate through arrays.

Anyway, using the existing structure, you can still improve by using array functions, such as `find` and `map`:

```js
class App {
    constructor(preview, objName, fields) {
        this.preview = preview;
        this.objName = objName;
        this.fields = fields;
        this.setNumbers();
    }

    setNumbers() {
        this.objName = this.objName.map( arr => arr.concat(this.preview[0][arr[0]]) );
        this.setStrings();
    }

    setStrings() {
        this.objName = this.objName.map( arr =>
            [arr[0]].concat(arr.slice(1).map( val =>
                this.fields.find( field => arr[0] in field )[arr[0]]
                           .find( item => item.id === val ).name
            ))
        );
        console.log(this.objName);
    }
}

var objName = [['obj1'], ['obj2']],
    preview = [{
        obj1: [1, 2],
        obj2: [3, 4]
    }],
    fields = [{
        obj1:[{
            id:1,
            name:'string_name1'
        }, {
            id:2, 
            name:'string_name2'
        }]
    }, {
        obj2:[{
            id:3, 
            name:'string_name3'
        }, {
            id:4, 
            name:'string_name4'
        }]
    }];

new App(preview, objName, fields);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note that this code assumes all searches lead to matches. If this is not your case, you'll have to add some code to define which values should be returned in case of non-matching references.

Here is such a variant of the code:

```js
class App {
    constructor(preview, objName, fields) {
        this.preview = preview;
        this.objName = objName;
        this.fields = fields;
        this.setNumbers();
    }

    setNumbers() {
        this.objName = this.objName.map( arr => 
            arr[0] in this.preview[0]
                ? arr.concat(this.preview[0][arr[0]])
                : arr
        );
        this.setStrings();
    }

    setStrings() {
        this.objName = this.objName.map( arr =>
            [arr[0]].concat(arr.slice(1).map( val => {
                let find = this.fields.find( field => arr[0] in field );
                if (find) find = find[arr[0]].find( item => item.id === val );
                return find ? find.name : val;
            }))
        );
        console.log(this.objName);
    }
}

var objName = [['obj1'], ['obj2'], ['obj3']],
    preview = [{
        obj1: [1, 2],
        obj2: [3, 4, 5],
    }],
    fields = [{
        obj1:[{
            id:1,
            name:'string_name1'
        }, {
            id:2, 
            name:'string_name2'
        }]
    }, {
        obj2:[{
            id:3, 
            name:'string_name3'
        }, {
            id:4, 
            name:'string_name4'
        }]
    }];

new App(preview, objName, fields);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this works well, I really need to improve on my array handling! and yes I had to add some extra code, for non matches

Comment: You're welcome. Good to hear you sorted out the code for non-matches.

Comment: @Roy Both of the solutions I provided handle for non-matches, both in the `obj...` names and in the id numbers (though I had to fix one small place where I was using `.map` instead of `.filter` to filter out the non-matches. Did you have a look at my answer?

Comment: Just to demo that dealing with non matches can be done with slight changes to my answer (which the OP was able to do themselves), I have now added such a variant explicitly to my answer. There are of course several ways to deal with non-matches: one can decide to filter out the offending values, or to keep them in without any mapping.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier and cleaner to do this if you break it down into smaller pieces:

```js
let objsToMap = [{
  obj1: [1, 2, 7],
  obj2: [3, 4],
  obj3: [1, 2]
}]

let objValues = [{
  obj1: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'string_name1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'string_name2'
  }]
}, {
  obj2: [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'string_name3'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'string_name4'
  }]
}];

function findValueForId(objDef, id) {
  let idKeyMap = objDef.find(item => item.id === id);

  return idKeyMap ? idKeyMap.name : null;
}

function findObjectValues(valueMapping, key) {
  let objectWithObjectValues = valueMapping.find(item => key in item);

  return objectWithObjectValues ? objectWithObjectValues[key] : null;
}

// returns an array containing key followed by the values corresponding to the specified ids
function lookupObject(key, ids, valueMapping) {
  let objDef = findObjectValues(valueMapping, key) || [];
  let valuesForIds = ids.map(id => findValueForId(objDef, id));
  let valuesWithoutBlanks = valuesForIds.filter(value => value);

  return [key].concat(valuesWithoutBlanks);
}


let result = Object.entries(objsToMap[0]).map(([k, v]) => lookupObject(k, v, objValues));

console.log(result);
```

You'll notice that this approach uses `.find()` in two places because your second data structure nests everything into arrays instead of having direct property references. This isn't very good because it's not good for performance and makes the code more convoluted than it has to be.

Another option is to rearrange the second array before consuming it, so that it's like this:

```
let objValues = {
  obj1: { 
    '1': 'string_name1',
    '2': 'string_name2'
  },
  obj2: {
    '3': 'string_name3', 
    '4': 'string_name4'
  }
};
```

Here's how you could do that:

```js
let objsToMap = [{
  obj1: [1, 2, 7],
  obj2: [3, 4],
  obj3: [1, 2]
}]

let objValuesRaw = [{
  obj1: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'string_name1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'string_name2'
  }]
}, {
  obj2: [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'string_name3'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'string_name4'
  }]
}];

function cleanupObjDef(objDef) {
  return objDef.reduce(function(acc, el) {
    acc[el.id] = el.name;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function cleanupObjValues(objValues) {
  let allCombined = Object.assign({}, ...objValues);

  return Object.entries(allCombined).reduce(function (acc, [k, v]) {
    acc[k] = cleanupObjDef(v);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}


// returns an array containing key followed by the values corresponding to the specified ids
function lookupObject(key, ids, valueMapping) {
  let objDef = valueMapping[key] || {};
  let valuesForIds = ids.map(id => objDef[id]);
  let valuesWithoutBlanks = valuesForIds.filter(value => value);

  return [key].concat(valuesWithoutBlanks);
}

let objValues = cleanupObjValues(objValuesRaw);
let result = Object.keys(objsToMap[0]).map(key => lookupObject(key, objsToMap[0][key], objValues));

console.log(result);
```